# Writing info into a tree

Tags: tikz-trees, forest

I want to draw this tree, but I want the data on the branches to be parallel to the branch, not like the result I am getting
Thank you!

```
  \documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper,fleqn]{report}


 \usepackage{forest}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \tikzset{
    dot/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.5,fill=black},
   }

  \begin{document}




 \begin{forest}
    [ ,name=a,for tree={s sep=50pt,l sep=5cm,dot,grow=1},
    [ ,name=b,edge label={node[midway, yshift=0.3cm,font=\small]{$p^2_1        =0.6,~ d_1^2=4$}}    
      [ ,name=c,edge label={node[midway, yshift=0.3cm,font=\small]{$p^3_4 =0.25,~ d_4^3=5$}}  ]
  [,name=d, edge label={node[midway, yshift=0.3cm,font=\small]{$p^3_3    =0.25,~ d_3^3=2$}}  ]    
  ]
    [ ,name=e, edge label={node[midway, yshift=0.3cm,font=\small]{$p^2_1 =0.4,~ d_1^2=1.5$}} 
    [,name=g,edge label={node[midway, yshift=0.3cm,font=\small]{$p^2_1 =0.3,~ d_2^3=5$}}  ]
      [,name=h,edge label={node[midway, yshift=0.3cm,font=\small]{$p^2_1 =0.2,~ d_1^3=2$}}  ]
   ]
 ]
 \node[yshift=-5cm,name= tiii,font=\small] at (a) {$t=1$};
 \node[name= tii,font=\small] at (c|-tiii) {$t=3$};
 \node[name= t,font=\small] at (b|-tii) {$t=2$};
\end{forest}


 \end{document}
```

Comment: I've edited my answer to tidy things up a bit and illustrate some further options for making the specification of the tree more concise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean that you want the edge labels to be sloped?

[image: sloped edge labels]

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz,a4paper,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\tikzset{
  dot/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.5,fill=black},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  my edge label/.style={
    edge label={node [midway, sloped, yshift=3mm, font=\small] {#1}}
  }
  [,name=a, for tree={s sep=50pt, l sep=5cm, dot, grow=0},
    [,name=b, my edge label={$p^2_1        =0.6,~ d_1^2=4$}
      [,name=c, my edge label={$p^3_4 =0.25,~ d_4^3=5$}
      ]
      [,name=d, my edge label={$p^3_3    =0.25,~ d_3^3=2$}
      ]
    ]
    [,name=e, my edge label={$p^2_1 =0.4,~ d_1^2=1.5$}
      [,name=g, my edge label={$p^2_1 =0.3,~ d_2^3=5$}
      ]
      [,name=h, my edge label={$p^2_1 =0.2,~ d_1^3=2$}
      ]
    ]
  ]
 \node[yshift=-5cm,name= tiii,font=\small] at (a) {$t=1$};
 \node[name= tii,font=\small] at (c|-tiii) {$t=3$};
 \node[name= t,font=\small] at (b|-tii) {$t=2$};
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

## EDIT

You might also consider adjusting the style of the edge labels somewhat, as [Very23 suggests](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/253067/). For example:

```
  my edge label/.style={
    edge label={node [pos=.6, auto, anchor=south, sloped, font=\small] {#1}}
  }
```

[image: adjusted positioning]

Or you could set things up so that the lower branch's label goes below the line, as in Very23's example, but have `forest` worry about when this is the case:

```
  /tikz/my edge labels/.style={pos=.6, sloped, font=\small},
  my edge label/.style={
    if n=1{
      edge label={node [my edge labels, below] {#1}}
    }
    {
      edge label={node [my edge labels, above] {#1}}
    }
  }
```

[image: automatic label placement]

### Complete code

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz,a4paper,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\tikzset{
  dot/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.5,fill=black},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  /tikz/my edge labels/.style={pos=.6, sloped, font=\small},
  my edge label/.style={
    if n=1{
      edge label={node [my edge labels, below] {#1}}
    }
    {
      edge label={node [my edge labels, above] {#1}}
    }
  }
  [,name=a, for tree={s sep=50pt, l sep=5cm, dot, grow=0},
    [,name=b, my edge label={$p^2_1        =0.6,~ d_1^2=4$}
      [,name=c, my edge label={$p^3_4 =0.25,~ d_4^3=5$}
      ]
      [,name=d, my edge label={$p^3_3    =0.25,~ d_3^3=2$}
      ]
    ]
    [,name=e, my edge label={$p^2_1 =0.4,~ d_1^2=1.5$}
      [,name=g, my edge label={$p^2_1 =0.3,~ d_2^3=5$}
      ]
      [,name=h, my edge label={$p^2_1 =0.2,~ d_1^3=2$}
      ]
    ]
  ]
 \node[yshift=-5cm,name= tiii,font=\small] at (a) {$t=1$};
 \node[name= tii,font=\small] at (c|-tiii) {$t=3$};
 \node[name= t,font=\small] at (b|-tii) {$t=2$};
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

If you wanted to really make use of `forest`'s power (or, at least, a little more of it), you could also specify the `t=` labels as part of the tree and create a style for convenience. For example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz,a4paper,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\tikzset{
  dot/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.5,fill=black},
}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  /tikz/my edge labels/.style={pos=.6, sloped, font=\small},
  my edge label/.style={
    if n=1{
      edge label={node [my edge labels, below] {#1}}
    }
    {
      edge label={node [my edge labels, above] {#1}}
    }
  },
  t value/.style={
    tikz={\node [font=\small, below=2cm of |- c] {$t=#1$};}
  }
  [,name=a, for tree={s sep=50pt, l sep=5cm, dot, grow=0}, t value=1
    [,name=b, my edge label={$p^2_1        =0.6,~ d_1^2=4$}, t value=2
      [,name=c, my edge label={$p^3_4 =0.25,~ d_4^3=5$}, t value=3
      ]
      [,name=d, my edge label={$p^3_3    =0.25,~ d_3^3=2$}
      ]
    ]
    [,name=e, my edge label={$p^2_1 =0.4,~ d_1^2=1.5$}
      [,name=g, my edge label={$p^2_1 =0.3,~ d_2^3=5$}
      ]
      [,name=h, my edge label={$p^2_1 =0.2,~ d_1^3=2$}
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

The only node which *needs* to be named here is `c` but I've left the others as naming them often turns out to be useful anyway.

Here is the (very similar) output:

[image: similar result]

Answer (score 5):

As @cfr mentioned in his answer you want your edge labels to be sloped but with removing the yshift option in the nodes c and g you will get something like this

[image]

the code

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper,fleqn]{report}


\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
dot/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.5,fill=black},}

\begin{document}




\begin{forest}
[,name=a,for tree={s sep=50pt,l sep=5cm,dot,grow=1},
[,name=b,edge label={node[midway, yshift=0.3cm,font=\small,sloped]{$p^2_1=0.6,~ d_1^2=4$}}    
[,name=c,edge label={node[midway,font=\small,sloped,below]{$p^3_4 =0.25,~ d_4^3=5$}}  ]
[,name=d, edge label={node[midway, yshift=0.3cm,font=\small,sloped]{$p^3_3    =0.25,~ d_3^3=2$}}  ] ]
[,name=e, edge label={node[midway, yshift=0.3cm,font=\small,sloped]{$p^2_1 =0.4,~ d_1^2=1.5$}} 
[,name=g,edge label={node[midway,font=\small,sloped,below]{$p^2_1 =0.3,~ d_2^3=5$}}  ]
[,name=h,edge label={node[midway, yshift=0.3cm,font=\small,sloped]{$p^2_1 =0.2,~ d_1^3=2$}}  ] ]]
\node[yshift=-5cm,name= tiii,font=\small] at (a) {$t=1$};
\node[name= tii,font=\small] at (c|-tiii) {$t=3$};
\node[name= t,font=\small] at (b|-tii) {$t=2$};
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I apologise for the fact that I probably edited your answer for no reason whatsoever. Your image did not appear (for me) and, not realising that the problem was probably my end, I edited your answer to ensure that the image appeared as intended. And, of course, this appeared to work - the image appeared for me. However, discussion in chat has since suggested something weird was going on specific to me (or is going on? can't tell yet) which has nothing to do with the actual question content. So I'm sorry for messing unnecessarily with your question. I assure you I had only good intentions!

Comment: don't you worry @cfr everything is fine you won me by a few seconds though :)

Comment: So it goes :(. I'm fond of `forest`... ;). You do have more up-votes, though.